# SQL specific time with a moving date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using MS SQL and I'd like to have a query that is basically

```
SELECT * FROM Data Where TimeStamp <= 06:30:00 Last Saturday
```

Anyone have anything functional to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get that time for last Saturday using `30` minutes and `6*60` for minutes in 6 hours (you can get this a few ways but I hard coded it using that:

```
DATEADD(MINUTE,(30 + (6 * 60) ), DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), -2))
```

Then you can use that in the where clause:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM dbo.Data AS d
WHERE 
    d.TimeStamp <= DATEADD(MINUTE,(30 + (6 * 60) ), DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), -2))
```

---

UPDATE: TLDR;  Break this down using a sample query: (hopefully it helps)

```
DECLARE @MyDatetime AS DATETIME = '2021-09-12 03:02:05.257'  --CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
SELECT
@MyDatetime AS FromWhen,
/* all these are The int difference between the startdate and enddate, expressed in the boundary set by datepart (WEEK)) */
DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @MyDatetime) AS MyWeek0, 
DATEDIFF(WEEK, -1, @MyDatetime) AS MyWeek1, 
DATEDIFF(WEEK, -2, @MyDatetime) AS MyWeek2, 
DATEDIFF(WEEK, -3, @MyDatetime) AS MyWeek3, 
DATEDIFF(WEEK, -4, @MyDatetime) AS MyWeek4, 
DATEDIFF(WEEK, -5, @MyDatetime) AS MyWeek5, 
DATEDIFF(WEEK, -6, @MyDatetime) AS MyWeek6, 
DATEDIFF(WEEK, -7, @MyDatetime) AS MyWeek7, 
DATEDIFF(WEEK, -8, @MyDatetime) AS MyWeek8, 
DATEDIFF(WEEK, -1, @MyDatetime) AS AWeekBack, -- get the week a week from RightNow DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )  
DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, -1, @MyDatetime), -2) AS Saturday0000, -- Get the Saturday date from that (-2 is saturday, -1 sunday, ...-7 monday)
DATEADD(MINUTE,(30 + (6 * 60) ), DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, -1, @MyDatetime), -2)) AS Saturday0630 -- now add the minutes for 6:30 AM to that saturday date
```

Values for a given set from that query:

> FromWhen  MyWeek0 MyWeek1 MyWeek2 MyWeek3 MyWeek4 MyWeek5 MyWeek6 MyWeek7 MyWeek8 AWeekBack   Saturday0000    Saturday0630
>
> 2021-09-12 03:02:05.257   6350    6350    6351    6351    6351    6351    6351    6351    6351    6350    2021-09-11 00:00:00.000 2021-09-11 06:30:00.000

Broken down:
Go back a week (-1)  from NOW
DATEDIFF always uses Sunday as the first day of the week to ensure the function operates in a deterministic way this -2 is Saturday.

```
DATEDIFF(WEEK, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

For example this is one query I use often get get those few thousand rows from a 120 second range on a given DATETIME column:

```
SELECT *
FROM SomeTable AS st
WHERE
    st.DateColumn >= DATEADD(SECOND, -60, @SomeDateTime)
    AND st.DateColumn < DATEADD(SECOND, 60, @SomeDateTime)
```

Comment: I'll delete my answer. I looked at your answer and thought it wouldn't work and created my own. Yours works. I will upvote.

Comment: This works great, for my understanding this is setting 6:30 in minutes to add from midnight, then it subtracts a week from current TS? actually could you explain what  DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), -2) is doing?

Comment: I added some notes and a query you can independently run to see some values - I posted the results right below that, each of the columns is one part of the combination

Answer (score 1):

With a [calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand), this is quite logical. Get me the highest row from the table that is a Saturday before today.

```
DECLARE @d smalldatetime;

SELECT @d = DATEADD(MINUTE, 390, MAX(TheDate))
  FROM dbo.CalendarTable
  WHERE TheDayName = 'Saturday'
    AND TheDate < CONVERT(date, GETDATE());

SELECT ... FROM dbo.Data WHERE [TimeStamp]/*shudder*/ <= @d;
```

Without a calendar table, you can do this in a slightly less intuitive way, by picking a *known* Saturday in the past, and adding the number of weeks that have passed since that date, less 1:

```
DECLARE @KnownSat smalldatetime = '20110101';

SELECT @d = DATEADD(MINUTE, 390, DATEADD
            (
              WEEK, 
              DATEDIFF(WEEK, @KnownSat, GETDATE()) - 1,
              @KnownSat
            ));

SELECT ... FROM dbo.Data WHERE [TimeStamp]/*shudder*/ <= @d;
```

Note that both solutions will return the previous Saturday when run on a Saturday.